# Jenkins, TestNG, WebDriver: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: selenium, jenkins, grid, webdriver, testng

Sometimes when I run my auto-tests (Jenkins, TestNG, WebDriver, Selenium Grid) I see following  output:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:306)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:129)
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateTable(TestHTMLReporter.java:159)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog(TestHTMLReporter.java:305)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish(TestHTMLReporter.java:40)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1040)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1188)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1025)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:115)
    ... 9 more
```

I can see that there are enough of disk space 2.55 GB, Windows Task Manager shows 1.39 GB in use.
How can I avoid it? Thanks

Comment: What version of testng you are on?

Comment: TestNG version is: 6.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this blog might help

http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/building-a-self-maintaining-grid-environment/

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be solved with newer versions of testng .  check this thread out : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/291